How to access slots within a class?
Given a class definition, is it possible to define one slot in terms of another, similar to how I would do it with let*?
For example, I would like to be able to do something like this (which obviously doesn't work):
(defclass foo ()
  ((x :initform 1 :accessor x)
   (y :initform (+ 1 x) :accessor y)))


I'd just write a custom constructor function that calls make-instance with the appropriate values

In DEFCLASS slot descriptions one can't refer to slots.
A typical way is to write an :after method for initialize-instance:
(defclass foo ()
  ((x :initform 1 :accessor foo-x)
   (y             :accessor foo-y)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((object foo) &rest args)
  (with-slots (x y) object
    (setf y (1+ x))))

CL-USER 44 > (make-instance 'foo)
#<FOO 81B0161EEB>

CL-USER 45 > (describe *)

#<FOO 81B0161EEB> is a FOO
X      1
Y      2


Thanks, Rainer! Exactly what I was looking for.
